# SQLite with Metro - Unable to load sqlite3.dll

Tags: c#, xaml, sqlite, microsoft-metro

I am not able to create a database using SQLite with my Metro application.

**Description:**
I continue to receive a runtime exception on a failure to load SQLite3.dll.

**Observation:**
I observed that the database directory never gets created in the app package's LocalState directory.
After observing this, I literally implemented file path creation at runtime and dropped the sqlite3.dll in the intended location.

Yet, I still receive an exception on failed to load SQLite3.dll.

1. My CRUD code that leverages SQLite compiles fine.
2. SQLite dependencies (packages.config, SQLite.cs, and sqlite3.dll) are located in a separate metro class library instead of the application's executable project.
3. The sqlite3.dll is based on the ARM processor.
4. The sqlite3.dll is set to Content, Copy Always.

**Code:**

```
    SQLiteAsyncConnection connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DATABASE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
    return await connection.CreateTableAsync<Service>();
```

Please help...

Comment: \Projects\MyProject\DAL\Local\Infrastructure\sqlite3.dll

Comment: Have you tried to put the dll in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: I am successful when I add the DAL assemblies to the metro app executable. However, when I take the same assemblies and dump them into a general Metro class library, the database creation continues to fail.

Comment: Perhaps I can create the database in the metro app exe and then try to delegate CRUD operations in a separate project that's specifically responsible for handling DAL operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error.After that I have placed sqlite3.dll in my root folder of the project
the sqlite3.dll is set to Content, Copy Always. after that it's working