# Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3' in SQLite Net Platform WinRT

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I am in process of developing native app using Xamarin.Forms. But the problem I am facing now is not related with Xamarin. I added new Windows Phone project by

`right-click > Add > New Project -> Windows Phone Apps -> Blank App(Windows Phone).`

in my existing Xamarin project in Visual Studio premium 2013. I am using sqlitenet pcl for database connection. I have below code in my project.

```
public ISQLitePlatform CreateSqlitePlatformInterface()
        {
            return new SQLitePlatformWinRT();
        }
```

When it executes above line, it throws exception as

```
An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

This has been asked many many times and I tried all suggested solution, still I am not able to fix it.

My Packages.config

```
 <package id="SQLite.Net-PCL" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="wpa81" />
  <package id="Sqlite-Winrt" version="3.8.7.1" targetFramework="wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="1.4.2.6359" targetFramework="wpa81" />
```

Above are the packages I downloaded from Nuget. Am I missing anything? What else I need to add?

Also I tried:

1. Downloaded **sqlite-winrt81-3081002.vsix** from [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) download
   page.
2. Copied sqlite3.dll from x86.
3. Tried pasting it in my **bin**
   folder as well as in my project **root** and changed it content to
   copy always. ([ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744293/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exceptio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744293/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exceptio))
4. My project is targeting **x86** not **Any CPU**.

Tried suggested solution from: [Sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328490/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-in-my-wpf-app), [Sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001731/sqlite-with-metro-unable-to-load-sqlite3-dll)

My Project References:

[image]

Comment: I installed vs extension, but I didn't add any reference to my project. Actually I downloaded that to get sqlite3.dll which I am referencing in my project. sorry, I am not sure, what else I have to refer?

Comment: Nm, sounds like you did.

Comment: Yeah, but that dll I got from Nuget, I didn't reference it manually.

Comment: Like http://robtiffany.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/6.png

Comment: After installing the extension from nuget you still need to reference it, like in the pic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After installing the SQLite Visual Studio Extension, you need to add a reference To the `SQLite for Windows Runtime` In Reference Manager under Windows / Extensions.

[Like this.](http://robtiffany.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/6.png)

Answer (score 10):

I experienced a different flavour of this error after some March 2016 updates to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015: my app would run fine when deployed to my desktop but crash with the System.DllNotFoundException (“Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3'") when deployed to my tablet (even after updating the tablets OS with the latest updates). So my steps to resolve the problem were as follows:

1. Uninstalled the VS extension called “SQLite for Universal App Platform” (v3.10.2)
2. Removed the reference to this extension from my project
3. Installed the extension again--except this time it showed up in the online extensions list as “SQLite for Universal **Windows** Platform” (v3.12.1)
4. Added the reference to this extension to my project
5. (this is the important part, which I didn't need to do before): Added a reference to the "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps” (v14.0) extension

It wasn't until that last step that it actually fixed the problem.

Comment: How do you know that it needs a reference to visual c++ 2015?

Comment: on the add reference window, when you select "SQLite for UWP", there's a tab on the right which gives some info and lists references- it says that it's dependent on VLC 14.0, I suppose it's Visual L(anguage?) C++.

Meanwhile, my project works without me manually adding the VLC, perhaps it was added behind the scenes

Comment: Worked for me. Must add a reference to the "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps” (v14.0) extension as well.